# sources.zip for 4.0.3 r3

Tags: android

I am trying to get sources.zip for android version 4.0.3.I downloaded `com.android.ide.eclipse.source_16.0.0.201112171909`
which contains `3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 14`

I'm looking for 15 so I can put the `sources.zip` from that in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-15`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i am not so clear about your question, but you can get All the Source Code from the [Google Source Code](http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/)

and for Particular Source Code of `4.0.3 r3` you can Download from [4.0.3 r3 Source Code](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/)

**EDITED :**

you Just have to Download the Source Folder from the second Link i have Given you.

you will get jar file like **`android-4.0.3_r1-sources.jar`** Download it

Place it Inside Android-15 folder.

Now Whne you press F3 on "Activity"  you will show **`Activity.class`** file and also Button with **`Attach Source Code`** by Clicking on it you will ask to Enter the Path of you jar file. Put here the Path of `../android-15-->android-4.0.3_r1-sources.jar` and Thats it. after that you will see the Inside coding of Activity Class.

**Also Make Sure you are Placing the Jar file of same version as Target Version of Application**

Hope it will help you.

Comment: i'm actually looking for a zip file sources.zip where i could point eclipse to that zip file and then i can see for example Activity.class source code and also debug apps and step into the code without getting a "source not found" error

Comment: yes, that folder is there, android-15, it has an android.jar         C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-15      in android sdk manager, i see: Sources for Android SDK API 15 Rev 2 (Installed) but Java still gives error "source not found" it wants a sources.zip which contains the source files

Comment: so what the problem you are facing?

Comment: when i press F3 on "Activity" it doesn't take me to the code, it gives error The JAR file "C:\Program Files(x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-15\android.jar has no source attachment. You can attach the source by clicking Attach source below.

Comment: Edited my answer. take look at it. I think it will solve your problem.let me know if you are facing difficulty again.

Comment: @user1848850 : have you found the Solution?

Comment: btw thank you, your answer is the right one, i didn't notice u put a msg, but thanks again. (i had to look for this answer this time again because i reinstalled windows and had to redo eclipse from scratch) thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Open Android SDK Manager n your eclipse and there you can download 15 version.

Comment: i did download version 15 source code and install it, but that doesn't fix the "sources not found" error i receive when debugging. It seems to require a sources.zip to point to and then i'm able to debug and see the code for Activity.class for example. I downloaded the sources.zip for sdk 10 and put it, and i can debug 2.3.3 but i'm trying to get 4.0.3 going

Comment: Have you download android-15. If yes, then place it into   Android-sdks -> platforms. This trick was worked in y case.